# Get main project's version in a referenced project

Tags: c#, reference, version, project

I have a `Main` project which have a reference to a project `Sub`, which is a class library.
In `Sub` I have a custom UI-control that display the version of my application.
This control is used in several locations in my application. Not only the `Main` project. 
My application's version is the `Main` project's version from the AssemblyInfo file.

I'm looking for a way to get the `Main` project's version in the `Sub` project.
I have found this line that I run in my UserControl:

```
var mainVersion = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName("ThePathToMain.exe").Version;
```

This will give me the `Main` project's version which is what I want.

**Question**
Is there another way to do this?
Or is there a way to avoid the hardcoded string to the `Main` project's executable?

I cannot have the UserControl in my `Main` project since it's used in other projects in my solution.
Having the `Main` project as a reference in the `Sub` project will cause circle references and will not work.

Comment: You can use `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName()`, assuming your Main project is executable and not used by yet another project.

Comment: If you have winforms projects, you could also use [Application.ProductVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.productversion?view=windowsdesktop-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Evk, I found this solution:

```
var name = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName();
var parts = name.CodeBase.Split('/');
var executable = parts.Last();
var version = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(executable).Version;
```

Comment: Why are you doing it this way and not as proposed by @Evk? Your variable `name` already has the Version you are looking for.